# PHP returning incorrect time

Tags: php

Running date from SSH on my server confirms server time is set correctly.
The code below produces a result that is 4 hours ahead of local time.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $now = new DateTime();
    $rsnew['updated'] = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
 ?>
```

Server Local Time: Thu Jun 19 09:36:41 EDT 2014
Time returned by code above: 2014-06-19 13:36:51

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance.

Working off of Rakish's example, the following code produces the desired result. That doesn't explain WHY my code wasn't working, but I'm good with the results.

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$ny_time = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime->setTimezone($ny_time);
$rsnew['updated'] = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Check out [Server is the wrong time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872619/server-is-the-wrong-time)

Comment: `$rsnew['updated'] = (new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: @JohnConde How will this solve the problem?

Comment: @hek2mgl I just threw it out there for them to try. That's why it is a comment and not an answer. (and touché)

Comment: What if you just execute this: http://3v4l.org/vEgDh ? Meaning immediately output the value. (Currently you are just putting it into an array and output it *somewhere*)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

I defined the specific problem: "Running date from SSH on my server confirms server time is set correctly. The code below produces a result that is 4 hours ahead of local time."

Implied in that statement is the desired result: Having the correct time produced.
The code in the posting represents the shortest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. So why is the question Off Topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `date()`

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

using `datetime` use `setTimezone()`

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$ny_time = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$datetime->setTimezone($ny_time);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: How will this solve their problem?

Comment: @JohnConde please check now updated

Comment: Rakesh Sharma; No change. Thanks for the try.

Comment: @Len_D let me explain if you comes up with date_default_timezone_set() it's sets timezone for date() if you using datetime then need to use settimezone()

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file and verify if the timezone is correct:

date.timezone = "America/New_York"

Since php5.1; the date_default_timezone_set will not work anymore. You will see an error in your errorlog.

Gr.

Comment: You misunderstood the documentation. The function exists since PHP 5.1

Comment: php.ini was set correctly.  Problem continues.

Comment: What kind of operatingsystem are you using?

Comment: @mlachman Don't you see that your answer is obviously wrong? How can a function *not working since 5.1 anymore* if it is only available since 5.1? Can you explain that?

Comment: I am running Apache over CentOS. Latest on both.

Comment: Working off of Rakesh's example. I got it working. That doesn't explain WHY my original code failed, but now I can move on to bigger and better things. Thanks Rakish.